# How can show a someone data in JSON on javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

```
        var example = {
        "Equation" : [{
        "name" : "My Equation",
        "xMin" : [41901.0840,4,3,5,2],
        "yMin" : [0.0000,4,5,7,8,9,3,1]
        }
    ]
};

        var e = JSON.parse(example);

        alert(e.example.xMin);
```

/* What's the problem, can't show any data on array object, at least xMin is Array, how can show someone number on array. Thanks!. */

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to parse since it's already a valid object. To get the property you need to get the `Equation` property and then it's the first element afterward get `xmin` property.

```js
var example = {
  "Equation": [{
    "name": "My Equation",
    "xMin": [41901.0840, 4, 3, 5, 2],
    "yMin": [0.0000, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 3, 1]
  }]
};


alert(example.Equation[0].xMin);
```

Comment: Perfect!. Thanks dude!.

Comment: @JailBreakRex :  glad to help :)